# OpenGL 2.1 glCreateShader is undefined

Tags: c++, opengl, fltk

I just started learning OpenGL with the help of [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/index.php) because I need some GUI functionality. My IDE is VS13 on Windows 7 and my graphics card driver supports OpenGL 2.1.

What I did was simply to run one of their examples and try to modify it a little bit but it failed to compile with something that should be pretty basic - the glCreateShader method which is included in OpenGL 2.1, it says "Error: identifier "glCreateShader" is undefined" although there are a lot of other gl- functions that are recognized. Here is the code, my function is at the end. If I comment it out it builds and runs:

```
//
// "$Id: cube.cxx 8864 2011-07-19 04:49:30Z greg.ercolano $"
//
// Another forms test program for the Fast Light Tool Kit (FLTK).
//
// Modified to have 2 cubes to test multiple OpenGL contexts
//
// Copyright 1998-2010 by Bill Spitzak and others.
//
// This library is free software. Distribution and use rights are outlined in
// the file "COPYING" which should have been included with this file.  If this
// file is missing or damaged, see the license at:
//
//     http://www.fltk.org/COPYING.php
//
// Please report all bugs and problems on the following page:
//
//     http://www.fltk.org/str.php
//

#include <config.h>
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Button.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Radio_Light_Button.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Slider.H>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>


#include <FL/Fl_Gl_Window.H>
#include <FL/gl.h>

class cube_box : public Fl_Gl_Window {
    void draw();
    int handle(int);
public:
    double lasttime;
    int wire;
    double size;
    double speed;
    cube_box(int x, int y, int w, int h, const char *l = 0)
        : Fl_Gl_Window(x, y, w, h, l) {
        lasttime = 0.0;
    }
};

/* The cube definition */
float v0[3] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
float v1[3] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
float v2[3] = { 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
float v3[3] = { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
float v4[3] = { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
float v5[3] = { 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
float v6[3] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
float v7[3] = { 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 };

#define v3f(x) glVertex3fv(x)

void drawcube(int wire) {
    /* Draw a colored cube */
    glBegin(wire ? GL_LINE_LOOP : GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3ub(0, 0, 255);
    v3f(v0); v3f(v1); v3f(v2); v3f(v3);
    glEnd();
    glBegin(wire ? GL_LINE_LOOP : GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3ub(0, 255, 255); v3f(v4); v3f(v5); v3f(v6); v3f(v7);
    glEnd();
    glBegin(wire ? GL_LINE_LOOP : GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3ub(255, 0, 255); v3f(v0); v3f(v1); v3f(v5); v3f(v4);
    glEnd();
    glBegin(wire ? GL_LINE_LOOP : GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3ub(255, 255, 0); v3f(v2); v3f(v3); v3f(v7); v3f(v6);
    glEnd();
    glBegin(wire ? GL_LINE_LOOP : GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3ub(0, 255, 0); v3f(v0); v3f(v4); v3f(v7); v3f(v3);
    glEnd();
    glBegin(wire ? GL_LINE_LOOP : GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3ub(255, 0, 0); v3f(v1); v3f(v2); v3f(v6); v3f(v5);
    glEnd();
}

void cube_box::draw() {
    lasttime = lasttime + speed;
    if (!valid()) {
        glLoadIdentity();
        glViewport(0, 0, w(), h());
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glFrustum(-1, 1, -1, 1, 2, 10000);
        glTranslatef(0, 0, -10);
        gl_font(FL_HELVETICA_BOLD, 16);
    }
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(float(lasttime*1.6), 0, 0, 1);
    glRotatef(float(lasttime*4.2), 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(float(lasttime*2.3), 0, 1, 0);
    glTranslatef(-1.0, 1.2f, -1.5);
    glScalef(float(size), float(size), float(size));
    drawcube(wire);
    glPopMatrix();
    gl_color(FL_GRAY);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl_draw(wire ? "Cube: wire" : "Cube: flat", -4.5f, -4.5f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

int cube_box::handle(int e) {
    switch (e) {
    case FL_ENTER: cursor(FL_CURSOR_CROSS); break;
    case FL_LEAVE: cursor(FL_CURSOR_DEFAULT); break;
    }
    return Fl_Gl_Window::handle(e);
}

Fl_Window *form;
Fl_Slider *speed, *size;
Fl_Button *button, *wire, *flat;
cube_box *cube;

void makeform(const char *name) {
    form = new Fl_Window(510 + 390, 390, name);
    new Fl_Box(FL_DOWN_FRAME, 20, 20, 350, 350, "");
    new Fl_Box(FL_DOWN_FRAME, 510, 20, 350, 350, "");
    speed = new Fl_Slider(FL_VERT_SLIDER, 390, 90, 40, 220, "Speed");
    size = new Fl_Slider(FL_VERT_SLIDER, 450, 90, 40, 220, "Size");
    wire = new Fl_Radio_Light_Button(390, 20, 100, 30, "Wire");
    flat = new Fl_Radio_Light_Button(390, 50, 100, 30, "Flat");
    button = new Fl_Button(390, 340, 100, 30, "Exit");
    cube = new cube_box(23, 23, 344, 344, 0);
    Fl_Box *b = new Fl_Box(FL_NO_BOX, cube->x(), size->y(),
        cube->w(), size->h(), 0);
    form->resizable(b);
    b->hide();
    form->end();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    makeform(argv[0]);
    // added to demo printing
    form->begin();

    form->end();
    // end of printing demo
    speed->bounds(4, 0);
    speed->value(cube->speed = 1.0);
    size->bounds(4, 0.01);
    size->value(cube->size = 1.0);
    flat->value(1); 
    cube->wire = 0; 
    form->label("cube");
    form->show(argc, argv);
    cube->show();

    for (;;) {
        if (form->visible() && speed->value()) {
            if (!Fl::check()) break;
        }   // returns immediately
        else                 {
if (!Fl::wait()) break;}    // waits until something happens
    cube->wire = wire->value();
    cube->size = size->value();
    cube->speed = speed->value();
    cube->redraw();
    if (Fl::readqueue() == button) break;
  }
  return 0;
}



//////////////////////////// Testing



GLuint CreateShader(GLenum eShaderType, const std::string &strShaderFile)
{
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(eShaderType);

    return shader;
}
```

Comment: You are on Windows. The only GL functions that will be defined out-of-the-box are from OpenGL 1.1. You need to load `glCreateShader (...)` using the extension loading mechanism, and the easiest way to do this is just to use [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Shouldn't it be also possible to load the core specification header?

Comment: @AdamS: Not if you actually intend to call the functions. All that will do is give you the function prototypes, there is no platform library you can link to on Windows that provides these functions at link-time. You have to load anything > GL 1.1 at run-time using `wglGetProcAddress (...)` (to load it from the Installable Client Driver) - GLEW makes this trivial.

Comment: It worked! I just had to include lib and it has macros definitions for the extensions! Thank you Andon, if you would answer the question I will mark it as the correct one.